# Simple lambda.R Script STDOUT funny business when invoking RScript with bash (Windows 7)

Tags: r, bash, lambda, stdout

### Goal:

I need to have a call to an RScript function output to `STDOUT` for redirection.

### Control: Control Script is

```
x = "Hello World"
x
```

Saved as control.R

**From bash**

```
$ RScript control.R
[1] "Hello World"
```

### Breaking:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# install.packages('lambda.r')
library('lambda.r')
greeting('en-US') %as% 'Hello'
greeting('en-GB') %as% 'Allo!'
greeting('en-AU') %as% 'GDay'
greeting('en-NZ') %as% 'Kia Ora!'
```

Saved as **greeting.R**

**From bash**

```
Master@L-BATESPRIME ~/Workspace/Lab/R
$ RScript greeting.R 'en-US'

Master@L-BATESPRIME ~/Workspace/Lab/R
$ RScript greeting.R 'en-NZ'

Master@L-BATESPRIME ~/Workspace/Lab/R
$ RScript greeting.R 'en-GB'

Master@L-BATESPRIME ~/Workspace/Lab/R
$
```

If I am running inside an R session (either in `RStudio` or `RGui`) whenever I call `greeting('my_arg')`, the R Console echos the correct value.  But, whenever I try to run the script through RScript from bash, I get an empty output.  I even attached a `System.Diagnostics.Process` over the command line to test this, wrapped over `STDIN` and tried to echo `STDOUT` to the console, but the stream contained an empty string.

How do I get:

```
Master@L-BATESPRIME ~/Workspace/Lab/R
$RScript greeting.R en-US
```

to echo out to bash?

Comment: Add `cat(...)` around the result?  Maybe `greeting()` returns invisibly...

Comment: Note that I only included the Windows 7 tag in case bash running in MinGW would make any difference (I assumed it wouldn't, but tagged the question as a marker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Notes

There are a few issues outside of the lack of an output statement. Specifically, I think the following needs to occur:

1. The script does not see the argument being passed in (e.g. the `en-US`) because there is no statement set to receive it (e.g. `args`).

   - Add to script: `args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE); msg = args[2]`
   - Modify call to: `Rscript greeting.R --args en-US`
2. You have defined, but not called the `greeting()` function with input. Thus, there will be no output.

   - To rectify this, add after the function declaration: `greeting(msg)`
   - To only return the greeting, enclose with `cat(...)`

## Proposed Changes

**From bash**

```
Rscript greetings.R --args en-US
```

**greetings.R**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Grab the commands
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

# Extract message
msg = args[2]

# Load in functional programming lib
library('lambda.r')

# Create functions
greeting('en-US') %as% 'Hello'

# install.packages('lambda.r')
library('lambda.r')
greeting('en-US') %as% 'Hello'
greeting('en-GB') %as% 'Allo!'
greeting('en-AU') %as% 'GDay'
greeting('en-NZ') %as% 'Kia Ora!'

# Call function with Greeting:
cat(greeting(msg),"\n")
```

## Desired output

**en-US**

```
$ Rscript greetings.R --args en-US
Hello
```

**en-GB**

```
$ Rscript greetings.R --args en-GB
Allo!
```

And so on...

Comment: Implementing your changes produces my desired output.  Are there any general resources you can recommend for writing automated R scripts instead of interactive R?  I'm having a bit of trouble finding information on how to have a daemon interface with R (everything I've come across assumes that a human is running the script from an interactive R Session)

Comment: @K.AlanBates I wrote up a brief post here http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/working-with-r-on-a-cluster/ that deals with distributed R usage via bash. Outside of that, I haven't run across the need yet for working with daemon's in R. Sorry.